# Why is Apollo's `useQuery` not returning consistent or correct results given the same query?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, graphql, shopify, apollo

I'm using `Apollo`, `graphql-tools`, and `jest` to test a GraphQL query using Shopify's Storefront API schema. First I used `Apollo` to download the schema from Shopify. I then made the schema executable and attempted to run a query on it. My query is for a `node` of type `Checkout`. There are several types that implement `node`, such as `Article`, `Blog`, `Comment`, etc.

I expect the query to return a `Checkout`, however it seems to randomly return any given type that implements `node`. Here is my code:

```
import { makeExecutableSchema, MockList, addMocksToSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import { printSchema, buildClientSchema } from 'graphql/utilities';
import { SchemaLink } from 'apollo-link-schema';
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from 'react-dom';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { ApolloProvider, useQuery, ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import React from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import introspectionResult from '../../../graphql/shopify_schema.json';

const query = gql`
  query($id: ID!) {
    node(id: $id) {
      ...cFrag
    }
  }
  fragment cFrag on Checkout {
    id
    email
    webUrl
  }
`;

const schemaSDL = printSchema(
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
  buildClientSchema(introspectionResult)
);

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: schemaSDL,
  resolverValidationOptions: {
    requireResolversForResolveType: false,
  },
});

const mockResolvers = {
  URL: () => {
    return 'foo@xyz.com';
  },
};

const schemaWithMocks = addMocksToSchema({ schema, mocks: mockResolvers });

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new SchemaLink({ schema: schemaWithMocks }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    possibleTypes: {
      Checkout: ['cFrag'],
    },
  }),
});

const CheckoutComponent = ({ id }) => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(query, { variables: { id } });
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return <p>Error!</p>;
  }

  console.log(data);
  return <p>{JSON.stringify(data)}</p>;
};

let container = null;

beforeEach(() => {
  // setup a DOM element as a render target
  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
  // cleanup on exiting
  unmountComponentAtNode(container);
  container.remove();
  container = null;
});

test('Renders correctly', async () => {
  act(() => {
    render(
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <CheckoutComponent id={1} />
      </ApolloProvider>,
      container
    );
  });
  expect(container.textContent).toContain('Loading...');
  await act(async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
  });
  expect(container.textContent).toContain('foo@xyz');
});
```

The test only passes when the query returns a `Checkout`. All other times it fails. An example of a failed result is:

```
expect(received).toContain(expected) // indexOf

    Expected substring: "foo@xyz.com"
    Received string:    "{\"node\":{\"__typename\":\"ShopPolicy\"}}"
```

When the query happens to return a `Checkout`, the test passes and the returned node has value:

```
{
      node: {
        __typename: 'Checkout',
        id: 'd5bf4a6e-d144-4eef-b1f5-5cc19342ba32',
        email: 'Hello World',
        webUrl: 'foo@xyz.com'
      }
}
```

My question is, why doesn't the query consistently return a `Checkout`? The query itself is clearly specifically for a `Checkout`.

Comment: Fragments are a way to specify a selection set by runtime type. They are not a way to filter the actual results of the query. See the linked dupe for details. There's nothing about your query that explicitly limits the result to a Checkout. `node` is just a way to fetch any type that implements by the `Node` interface. The only way to limit that to just checkouts is to ensure the ID you're passing in is for a checkout.

Comment: @DanielRearden Oh, that makes a lot more sense! Thanks for the tip on fragments. Do you know if I would be able to include an ID using the mocking framework I currently have (e.g. using `@apollo/client` and `graphql-tools`? I know I can mock resolvers for the fields that I want to query, but I'm unsure if it's possible to mock IDs. I'm using [this] (https://www.telerik.com/blogs/mocking-and-testing-graphql-in-react) as a guide, and I think the solution may be related to what's in the "Accessing Arguments" section towards the end of the article, but I can't figure out how to adapt it to my case

Comment: Mocking the entire schema is overkill for component testing. Check the official docs [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/). You can just provide the mocked data directly through `MockedProvider`.

Comment: @DanielRearden thanks again! In your opinion, in what situation would mocking the entire schema be the right move?

Comment: Schema mocking is typically used when you're developing the client app and the API has not been implemented (i.e. the type definitions are available, but the resolvers have not been implemented). It can also be helpful when creating a prototype or proof of concept.